# How to programmatically add onClick in the Panel in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to add onClick() or a function that is triggered on clicking the panel in visual studio programmatically

```
        Panel pan = new Panel
        {
            Location = new Point(0, y_coordinate),
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(986, 90),
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(240,245,248)


        };
```

Comment: A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+programmatically+add+onClick+C%23%3F) show the documentation regarding this specific point (2nd link). What difficulty are you facing ?

Comment: 1. Create Panel in designer 2. Add on click 3. check generated code ... bum dum tsssss .... in Windows forms it's always done programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
pan.Click += (_sender, _e) =>
{
  // ...
};
```

Or:

```
pan.Click += SomeMethod;

private void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // ...
}
```

It adds the lambda method or the class method to the Click event manager of the panel.

Don't forget to add the panel for example to the form or any other panel:

```
this.Controls.Add(pan);
```

Or:

```
panelSomewhere.Controls.Add(pan);
```